# Sharepoint framework (spfx) failes to create new project

Tags: spfx, npm

I use `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` and it hangs at `Found npm version 6.5.0,no error the console is not closing it just stops. (files are not produced and multiple enters don't do anything)
Guys do you have some suggestions? 
[image]

Comment: I used yo @microsoft/sharepoint and yo @microsoft/sharepoint --component-type "webpart" --framework "react" and it was the same result

Comment: Run npm update (Update to the latest npm and retry the step once again)

Comment: @AIM4DREAM npm update shouldn't update the package.json? the problem is that yeoman doesn't generate anything
I've recorded a gif of it here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nYmKw_Xh4ZTiybOLBXNc52dlnlRc5tIA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Try to reinstall node js version 8.* https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/ It is officaly supported version by Microsoft.
Then try to run yo generator without the parameters.  
Only yo @microsoft/sharepoint. 
Perhaps try to update Microsoft generator.